# Find all integers $n$ for which $x^6 + nx^2 − 1$ can be written as a product of two non-constant polynomials with integer coefficients.

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

Find all integers $n$ for which $x^6 + nx^2 − 1$ can be written as a product of two non-constant polynomials with integer coefficients.

I first tried expanding: $(x^3+ax^2+bx+1)(x^3+cx^2+dx-1)$ and equating coefficients.

This yields the following relationships:

$$a+c = 0$$
$$ac+b+d = 0$$
$$-b+d = 0$$

and
$$n = -a+bd+c$$

Is this the right approach? How should I go about doing it?

Comment: It also could be $(x^2+ax+b)(x^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex +f)=0$, or a degree $5$ times a linear factor.

Comment: And just by trying, certainly for $n=0,8$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not too difficult to do case-by-case. Write $f(x)=x^6+nx^2-1$.

1. By the rational root theorem, the only possible linear factors are $x\pm1$. They are both factors if and only if $n=0$, when $f(x)=(x-1)(x+1)(x^4+x^2+1)$.
2. The OP is well on their way to solving the case of two cubics. As the other steps also use this technique, let us record the fact that $f(x)$ is even. In other words $f(x)=f(-x)$. We combine this with the uniqueness of factorization of polynomials (up to unit factors). When concentrating on the case of a factorization into two irreducible cubics, $f(x)=p(x)q(x)$, we see that without loss of generality we can assume $p$ and $q$ to both be monic. As also $f(x)=p(-x)q(-x)$ we have two possibilities. Either $p(-x)=-p(x)$ or $p(-x)=-q(x)$. The former case is impossible, because then $p(0)=0$, and hence also $0=f(0)=1$, which is a contradiction. So if
   $p(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ then $q(x)=x^3-ax^2+bx-c$. Without loss of generality we can assume that $c=1$ (interchange $p$ and $q$ otherwise). In this case
   $$
   \begin{aligned}f(x)&=p(x)q(x)\\
   &=(x^3+bx)^2-(ax^2+1)^2\\
   &=x^6+(2b-a^2)x^4+(b^2-2a)x^2-1.
   \end{aligned}
   $$
   A look at the degree four terms tells us that $a$ must be even, say $a=2k$, and $b=2k^2$. Therfore the coefficient of the quadratic term is
   $$n=(2k^2)^2-2\cdot(2k)=4k^4-4k.$$
   Here the parameter $k$ can be any integer. The corresponding factorization is
   $$f(x)=(x^3+2kx^2+2k^2x+1)(x^3-2kx^2+2k^2x-1).$$
3. Let us then consider the case of $f(x)=p(x)q(x)$, where $p(x)$ is an irreducible quadratic factor. As above, we conclude that $p(-x)$ is also a factor. Either $p(x)=p(-x)$ or $q(x)=p(-x)r(x)$ where $r(x)$ is yet another irreducible quadratic factor. As $r(-x)$ must also be a factor, in all cases we have either $p(x)=p(-x)$ or $r(x)=r(-x)$, and can conclude that $f(x)$ has a factor without the linear term. In other words $x^2-m\mid f(x)$ for some $m\in\Bbb{Z}$. Plugging in $x^2=m$ tells us that
   $$f(\sqrt m)=m^3+nm-1=0.$$
   Therefore
   $$m(m^2+n)=1.$$
   This allows us to conclude that either $m=1$, $n=0$ (a case covered earlier) or $m=-1$, $n=-2$. The new possibility we got out of this is thus
   $$
   f(x)=x^6-2x^2-1=(x^2+1)(x^4-x^2-1).
   $$

> Either $n=-2$ or $n=4k^4-4k$ for some integer $k$.

Answer (score 1):

We might also look at this polynomial $ \ x^6 + nx^2 − 1 \ $ in terms of what is possible for its zeroes.  Since it is an even-symmetry function, its real zeroes are symmetrically placed about the $ \ y-$axis.  Its "limits at infinity" are both "positive infinity", but its $ \ y-$intercept is negative, so it must have an even number of real zeroes.

However, we cannot have two "triple zeroes", as this would require the factorization $ \ (x - r)^3·(x + r)^3 \ = \ x^3 - 3r^2x^4 + 3r^4x^2 - r^6 \ \ , $ but the absence of a quartic term dictates that $ \ r = 0 \ . $  We also cannot have "double zeroes", as the factorization would be

$$  (x - r)^2 · (x + r)^2 · (x^2 + C) \ \ = \ \ x^6 \ + \ ( C - 2r^2 )·x^4 \ + \ (r^4 - 2Cr^2)·x^2 \ + \ Cr^4 \ \ \ , $$

with the quadratic factor being irreducible in $ \ \mathbb{R} \ . $ But the constant term $ \ Cr^4 \ = \ -1 \ \ , $ makes this  impossible, as the irreducibility condition (and the quartic term being absent) requires $ \ C \ > \ 0 \ \ . $   For the same reasons, there cannot be *four* distinct real zeroes, which leads to
$$    (x - r)  · (x + r)  · (x - s)  · (x + s)  · (x^2 + C) $$ $$ = \ \ x^6 \ + \ ( C -  r^2 - s^2)·x^4 \ + \ (r^2s^2 -  Cr^2 - Cs^2)·x^2 \ + \ Cr^2s^2 \ \ \ . $$

[We can also resolve this by the application of calculus.  The first derivative is $ \ 2x·(3x^4 + n) \ $ and the second derivative is $ \ 2·(15x^4 + n) \ \  . $  For $ \ n \ > \ 0 \ \ , $ the polynomial curve is always "concave upward" and so has a single absolute minimum at $ \ (0 \ , \ -1) \ $ and "crosses" the $ \ x-$axis only twice.  In the case of $ \ n \ < \ 0 \ \ , $ there are three local extrema, those being  a relative maximum at $ \ (0 \ , \ -1) \ $ and two absolute minima at $ \ \left( \ \pm \sqrt[4]{\frac{|n|}{3}}  \ , \ y < -1 \right) $ ; again, the function curve "crosses" the $ \ x-$axis just twice.]

With the two real zeroes being  $ \ r \ $ and $ \ -r \ \ , $ the real coefficients and even symmetry of our polynomial require that its four complex zeroes must be $ \ \rho \ = \ \alpha + \beta i \ \ , \ \ -\rho  \ \ , \ \ \overline{\rho} \ \ , \ \ -\overline{\rho} \ \ . $  The factorization of the polynomial is thus

$$   (x - r) · (x + r) · (x - \rho) · (x - \overline{\rho}) · (x + \rho) · (x + \overline{\rho}) $$

$$ = \ \  (x^2 - r^2) · (x^2 - 2\alpha·x + \alpha^2 + \beta^2) · (x^2 + 2\alpha·x + \alpha^2 + \beta^2) $$

$$ = \ \  (x^2 - r^2) \ · \ ( \ x^4 \ + \ 2·[ \overbrace{\beta^2 - \alpha^2}^{D} ]·x^2 \ + \ [ \overbrace{\alpha^2 + \beta^2}^{M}   ]^2 \ )  $$

$$   = \ \ x^6 \ + \ (2D - r^2)·x^4 \ + \ (M^2 - 2Dr^2)·x^2 \ - \ M^2r^2 \ \ \ . \quad \quad \mathbf{[ \ A \ ]} $$

The conditions $ \ M^2r^2 \ = \ 1 \ $ and $ \ 2D - r^2 \ = \ 0 \ $  imply that
$$ 2D \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{M^2} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ n \ \ = \ \ M^2  \ - \ \frac{1}{M^4} \ \ = \ \ \frac{M^6 \ - \ 1}{M^4}  \ \ , $$

this last being an integer ( $ \ D \ $ and $ \ M \ $ generally *will not* be integers).

The "exceptional case" is that for which there are four purely imaginary zeroes ( $ \alpha \ = \ 0 \ $) , with $ \ \rho \ = \ -\overline{\rho} \ : \ 
\pm \beta i \ \ , \ \ \pm \gamma i \ \ . $  The factorization here is

$$   (x - r) · (x + r) · (x - \beta i) · (x + \beta i) · (x - \gamma i) · (x + \gamma i) \ \ = \ \  (x^2 - r^2) · (x^2 + \beta^2) · (x^2 + \gamma^2) $$

$$   = \ \ x^6 \ + \ (\beta^2 + \gamma^2 -  r^2)·x^4 \ + \ (\beta^2 \gamma^2 - \beta^2 r^2 - \gamma^2 r^2)·x^2 \ - \ \beta^2 \gamma^2 r^2 \ \ \ . \quad \quad \mathbf{[ \ B \ ]} $$

The conditions $ \ \beta^2 \gamma^2 r^2 \ = \ 1 \ $ and $ \ \beta^2 + \gamma^2 -  r^2 \ = \ 0 \ $  give us
$$ \beta^2 + \gamma^2 \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{\beta^2 \gamma^2} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ n \ \ = \ \ \beta^2 \gamma^2  \ - \ \frac{\beta^2 + \gamma^2}{\beta^2 \gamma^2} \ \ . $$

It is not straightforward generally to see how we would obtain integer values for $ \ n \ $ from these expressions, but the analysis of the roots shows that we only need to consider two factorizations for $ \ x^6 + nx^2 − 1 \ \ : $

one is the pair of cubic factors you were considering, each written here as having one real root and a complex-conjugate pair,
$$ [ \ (x - r) · (x + \rho) · (x + \overline{\rho}) \ ] \ · \ [ \ (x + r) · (x - \rho) · (x - \overline{\rho}) \ ]  $$
$$ = \ \ [ \ (x^3 \ + \ [2 \alpha - r]·x^2 \ + \ [\alpha^2 + \beta^2 - 2 \alpha r]·x \ - \ (\overbrace{\alpha^2 + \beta^2}^{M})·r \ ] $$
$$ · \ [ \ (x^3 \ - \ [2 \alpha - r]·x^2 \ + \ [\alpha^2 + \beta^2 - 2 \alpha r]·x \ + \ (\alpha^2 + \beta^2)·r \ ] \ \ , $$

which, with setting $ \ r \ = \ \frac{1}{M} \ \ , $ produces the factorization
$$  ( \ x^3 \ + \ Bx^2 \ + \ Cx \ - \ 1 \ ) \ · \ ( \  x^3 \ - \ Bx^2 \ + \ Cx \ + \ 1 \ ) \ \ ;  \quad \quad \mathbf{[ \ C \ ]} $$

the other is a pair of linear factors for the two real roots and a quartic factor, as described for $ \ \mathbf{[ \ B \ ]} \ $ above,
$$ (x^2 - r^2) · (x^2 + \beta^2) · (x^2 + \gamma^2) \ \ = \ \ (x^2 - r^2) · (x^4 \ + \ [\beta^2 + \gamma^2] · x^2 \ + \ \beta^2 \gamma^2) \ \ , $$

for which it will be convenient to set $  \ \beta^2 \gamma^2 \ = \ \frac{1}{r^2} \ \ , $ producing
$$ (x^2 - r^2) · \left( \ x^4 \ + \ A x^2 \ + \ \frac{1}{r^2} \ \right) \ \ .   \quad \quad \mathbf{[ \ B' \ ]} $$

We can now "multiply out" these factorizations to relate them to our original polynomial.  For $ \ \mathbf{[ \ C \ ]} \ , $ we obtain
$$  ( \ x^3 \ + \ Bx^2 \ + \ Cx \ - \ 1 \ ) \ · \ ( \  x^3 \ - \ Bx^2 \ + \ Cx \ + \ 1 \ ) $$ $$ = \ \ x^6 \ + \ [2C - B^2]·x^4 \ + \ [C^2 - 2B]·x^2 \ - \ 1 \ \ , $$
arriving a result also shown by **Jyrki Lahtonen**.  The "missing" quartic term requires that $ \ B^2 \ = \ 2C \ \ , $ so the quadratic coefficient is given by $ \ n \ = \ C^2 - 2·(\pm \sqrt{2C}) \ = \ C^2 \ \pm \ 2·\sqrt{2C} \ \ .  $  Since we wish this to be an integer, we take $ \ C \ $ to be an even integer
$$   C \ = \ 2m^2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ n \ = \ 4m^4 \ \pm \ 4m  \ \ , \ \ B \ = \ \pm \ 2m \ \ , $$
making the factorization
$$  ( \ x^3 \ - \ 2m·x^2 \ + \ 2m^2·x \ - \ 1 \ ) \ · \ ( \  x^3 \ + \ 2m·x^2 \ + \ 2m^2·x \ + \ 1 \ ) \ \ , $$
with $ \ m \ $ being any integer.  Examples are

$ \mathbf{m \ = \ 2 \ \Rightarrow \ n \ = \ 56 \ : } \quad x^6 \ + \ 56x^2 \ -  \ 1 $

$ = \ \ ( \ x^3 \ - \ 4x^2 \ + \ 8x \ - \ 1 \ ) \ · \ ( \  x^3 \ + \ 4x^2 \ + \ 8x \ + \ 1 \ ) $

and

$ \mathbf{m \ = \ -2 \ \Rightarrow \ n \ = \ 72 \ : } \quad x^6 \ + \ 72x^2 \ -  \ 1 $

$ = \ \ ( \ x^3 \ + \ 4x^2 \ + \ 8x \ - \ 1 \ ) \ · \ ( \  x^3 \ - \ 4x^2 \ + \ 8x \ + \ 1 \ ) \  . $

[Note that this includes the case $ \ m \ = \ n \ = \  0 \ \ , $ which "collapses" the factors to $ \ ( \  x^3 \  - \ 1 \ )   ·  ( \  x^3 \  + \ 1 \ ) \ \ , $ with the zeroes being the six complex sixth-roots of $ \ 1 \ \ . \ ]  $

Carrying out a similar analysis for $ \ \mathbf{[ \ B' \ ]} \ $ yields
$$ (x^2 - r^2) · \left( \ x^4 \ + \ A x^2 \ + \ \frac{1}{r^2} \ \right) \ \ = \ \ x^6 \ + \ [A \ - \ r^2]·x^4 \ + \ \left[\frac{1}{r^2} - Ar^2 \right]·x^2 \ - \ 1 \ \ . $$
The "vanishing" of the quartic term requires that
$$   r^2 \ = \ A \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ n \ = \ \frac{1}{A} \ - \ A^2 \ \ . $$
The possibilities for making this quadratic coefficient integral are limited to  $ \ A \ = \ 1 \ \Rightarrow \ n \ = \ 0 \ \ $ [ this case does not properly "fit" here, since none of the zeroes are purely imaginary] and $ \ A \ = \ -1 \ \Rightarrow \ n \ = \ -2 \ \ $ [which does not really "fit" with $ \ r \ $ being a real number, but this does produce a factorization of the desired sort -- this is the only case that the factorization $ \ \mathbf{[ \ C \ ]} \   $ cannot produce].  The two results here are
$$ x^6 \ - \ 1 \ \ = \ \ ( \ x^2 - 1 \ ) ·  ( \ x^4 \ + \  x^2 \ + \ 1 \  ) $$
and
$$ x^6 \ - \ 2x \ - \ 1 \ \ = \ \ ( \ x^2 + 1 \ ) ·  ( \ x^4 \ + \  x^2 \ - \ 1 \  ) \ \ , $$
this last polynomial having the zeroes $ \ \pm \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt5 \ - \ 1}{2}} \ \ , \ \ \pm \ i \ $ and $ \ \pm \ i·\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt5 \ + \ 1}{2}} \ \ . $ (The quartic polynomial having only the four complex-conjugate zeroes *does not* have integer coefficients.  Overall, $ \   x^6 \ - \ 2x \ - \ 1 \ $ is the "oddball" in this general scheme.)